# UITabBarController: как менять шрифт, размер и цвет?

Tags: objective-c

Скажите, как менять шрифт, размер и цвет в Таб Баре в меню UITabBarController?
С примером.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UITabBarItem *firstTab = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *secondTab = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

firstTab.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"about"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
firstTab.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"aboutHltd"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

secondTab.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"requestBtnTab"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
secondTab.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"requestBtnTabHltd"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

[firstTab setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.000 green:0.800 blue:1.000 alpha:1.000]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[firstTab setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:1]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[secondTab setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.600 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[secondTab setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:1]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```